# Texas Holdem Poker Game

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, playing-cards

I'm making a Texas Hold'em game for multiple players. So far, I have finished the flow control for betting / calling sequences, player stack / pot updating, and just now - the part responsible for drawing cards and distributing them. It is this last part that I would like reviewed, if possible.

Essentially, I wanted to know what I could do differently / more efficiently, suggested changes, really just anything that could be helpful. Things like checks for proper input from player etc are not yet in place so please ignore them.

```
import itertools
import random

player_count = int(input("How many players? "))

suits = ['s', 'c', 'd', 'h']
faces = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

# Defining deck and drawing cards (5 + 2 per player):

deck = set(itertools.product(faces, suits))
drawn_cards = random.sample(deck,(5 + 2 * player_count))

# Storing a list with player object instances

players = []

class Players:

    def __init__(self, stack):

        self.stack = stack
        self.last_action = "none"  ## last action taken (check, call etc). 
        self.street_bets = 0       ## total bets on current street

    def holecards(self):

## pop cards from list and pritifying their display. Cards will later be 
## run through a function for checking value of hands:

        card1 = drawn_cards.pop(len(drawn_cards)-1) 
        card2 = drawn_cards.pop(len(drawn_cards)-1) 
        self.card1 = (card1[0]+"["+card1[1]+"]")    
        self.card2 = (card2[0]+"["+card2[1]+"]")     
        self.cards = self.card1+ " - " +self.card2
        print (self.cards)      

class Table:

    def __init__(self):     

        self.total_pot = 0

    def flop(self):

        card1 = drawn_cards.pop(len(drawn_cards)-1)
        card2 = drawn_cards.pop(len(drawn_cards)-1) 
        card2 = drawn_cards.pop(len(drawn_cards)-1)
        self.card1 = (card1[0]+"["+card1[1]+"]")
        self.card2 = (card2[0]+"["+card2[1]+"]")     
        self.card3 = (card2[0]+"["+card2[1]+"]")
        self.flop = self.card1+ " - " + self.card2 + " - " + self.card3
        print (self.flop)

    def turn(self):

        card = drawn_cards.pop(len(drawn_cards)-1)
        self.card = (card[0]+"["+card[1]+"]")
        self.turn = self.card
        print (self.turn)

    def river(self):

        card = drawn_cards.pop(len(drawn_cards)-1)
        self.card = (card[0]+"["+card[1]+"]")
        self.river = self.card
        print (self.river)



# Add player stacks and distribute holecards:

for i in range(player_count):
    players.append(i)
    players[i] = Players(100)
    players[i].holecards()

# Add dealer to table:

dealer = Table()

dealer.flop()
dealer.turn()
dealer.river()
```

Answer (score 4):

Reasonable quality code. Here are a few comments:

1) I'd add a method `drawNextCard`, which encapsulates retrieval of the next card, and makes the code a bit more readable

```
def draw_next_card(drawn_cards):
    card = drawn_cards.pop(len(drawn_cards)-1)
    return readable_card_name(card)

def readable_card_name(short_card_name):
    return (short_card_name[0]+"["+short_card_name[1]+"]")
```

Then, for example, your `flop()` method would look like this:

```
def flop(self):
    (self.card1, self.card2, self.card3) = (draw_next_card(drawn_cards), draw_next_card(drawn_cards), draw_next_card(drawn_cards)) 
     self.flop = self.card1+ " - " + self.card2 + " - " + self.card3
     print (self.flop)
```

More readable, shorter, and on the way we fixed a copy/paste defect where you initialized `card2` twice instead of `card2` and `card3`.

2) You convert each drawn card to a readable representation. It's good for your debugging, but not so good for adding future functionality for actually calculating poker hands, and developing strategy. So, while my `draw_next_card` above returns a readable representation, you're better off creating a class `Card`, which has an `__str__` method that has the same implementation as `readable_class_name`. The `flop` method would remain the same, but it will be much easier to extend the code.

3) Note that `flop` and `river` are copy/pastes. Both could just call `draw_next_card`. Also, while the `flow` and `river` are true to the game terms, they're not much benefit to software; you'd be better off collapsing `flop`, `turn` and `river` to a `table_cards[5]` vector. Once you start developing the actual game, it will make things much easier for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I found no direct way to reply to you RomanK, but I had to say thank you. So - thank you!

**EDIT**: sorry for the "Thank you", I guess.

**Another question**: after thinking it through, does using a class for dealing and distributing the flop, turn and river make sense at all? Wouldn't I be better off just using a function for this? The more I think of it the less I see any reason for having this part of the code in a class - seems to be more of a problem than a convenience.

Essentially, after the hole cards have been dealt to the players, what remains in the `drawn_cards` list are the 5 cards for the board. All I need to do now is display them with a function:

```
def deal_community_cards(street):

    if street == "flop":
        flop = drawn_cards[0:3]
        return flop

    elif street == "turn":
        turn = drawn_cards[3]
        return turn

    else:
        river = drawn_cards[4]
        return river
```

and finally I'd use another function to "pritify" the card display. Wouldn't this be a better solution than creating a whole class for this?

Comment: Firstly, as forsvarir says, you're better off editing your own post, rather than adding an answer. Secondly, welcome.
As to your new question: consider that you don't always draw 5 cards - what happens if everyone folds after the flop? Also, as mentioned in my answer: not sure that you even need variables called `flop`, `turn` and `river` - they are helpful for poker players, but not to your code's logic.

Comment: Thanks again. So what you are suggesting is that, essentially, when I want to show the flop/turn/river cards to players, that all I do is just display the cards to them, ie. just `print (drawn_cards[0:3])` for the flop, and that's all. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.